# Missing dependency for .ocx on Windows CE 6.0

Tags: activex, windows-ce, ocx

I'm trying to make an ActiveX control for an application on a Windows CE 6.0 device, but I can't get it to register on the device. When I transfer the .ocx file over to the device and try to register it using regsvrce.exe, it fails with error 7e, which I've learned means a dependency is missing. How can I identify which dependency is missing? Alternatively, have I gone about creating the ActiveX control wrongly?

I have loaded the .ocx in Dependency Walker on my development machine (running Windows 7 64-bit, if that matters) and all of the top-level dependencies it lists are present on the CE device. I can't check further down the tree since Depends then looks for the top-level dependencies on my development machine, half of which are missing since they're CE-specific. Dependency Walker doesn't run on the CE device (unless there's a CE version I've missed?). I tried to copy the DLLs from the CE device to a flash drive so I could load them into DW on my development machine, but the device won't allow me to do so. The OEM tool I have for transferring files unfortunately only transfers *to* the device. [Edit: I haven't tried writing my own tool to try to pull files from the device to development machine.]

Some details on how I've set up the project, in case I have some wrong assumptions on that end. I have tried with two projects. One has my code in it (the ActiveX Control itself is just a graphical representation of some data, which I had originally set up in a win32 ActiveX control to see how it looks), and one is a clean project - created from template, compiled, downloaded to device; no code added or configuration changed. Both have the same result when trying to register.

- Using VS2005, created a project using the "MFC Smart Device ActiveX Control" template, targeting the SDK I received from the OEM.
- In the case of the project with my code in it, I copied my drawing code into the project and created the necessary properties for the data input. I can provide more details on my code if it would help, but my issue happens even without the code. I am assuming that since it compiles successfully when targeting the SDK from the OEM that the functions I am using are supposed to be available on the target device.
- Build the project in Release configuration (I wondered if the debug libraries were missing on the target device and causing the issue).
- Transfer the .ocx file to the target device using an OEM tool.
- Start command line on target device, move to directory the .ocx is in, run "regsvrce.exe .ocx". I have also tried transferring all of the files that VS leaves in the build output folder, but the result is the same.

Many thanks in advance for any answers! If you see something obvious point it out - this is my first ActiveX project and my first CE project, so it's very possible I'm missing something basic.

Comment: You have the proper MFC libraries over on the device (mfccexxx.dll, and either release or debug version etc)?  I don't recall if VS05 used newer MFC libs for linking apps than Platform Builder puts in the OS image, but I suspect that it does.  I know VS 08 does.

Comment: The device has mfcce400.dll. How can I check which library VS is using to link the app? I would have thought that VS2005 would use the same version as Platform Builder puts in the OS, since Platform Builder is a plugin for VS2005, but it's always good to check assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

Since you build `OCX` I assume that you are using `MFC`. How do you link with `MFC`? Look in project settings|General, try to select "Use MFC in a Static Library". Same goes for ATL - try selecting "Static Link to ATL" (if you use ATL). This goes also for VCRT - in C/C++|Code Generation, in "Runtime Library" try selecting options without the 'DLL' (i.e. - statically link with VCRT). 
Since the default empty OCX does not work for you - this is the only thing I can think of...
Another thing - I assume you have a reason for working with `Visaul Studio 2005`? Why not a newer version?
Good luck, PazO

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I am using MFC, and the project was already using MFC in a static library. It wasn't using ATL, so I've now tried using ATL with a static link as well. Also wasn't using a DLL option in C/C++|Code Generation. None of these options seem to change anything as far as getting the .ocx registered on the target device.

I'm using VS2005 because the SDK doesn't show up when creating a new project in later versions. 2005 is also the only full copy I have, so I'm sticking with it instead of relying on trial versions if possible.

Comment: Are you sure that the 'dependency missing' error is refering to your OCX and not to the regsvrc.exe tool? If so then I can only think of upgrading Visual Studio. You have all the 'Express' versions for free, maybe one of them could help?

Comment: I'm pretty certain it's referring to the ocx. When I run regsvrce, I get a popup with the message "Loadlibrary("MyActiveX.ocx") failed. GetLastError returns 7e". I'll try an express version and see if that changes anything.

Comment: My last advice would be to (a) use supported `Visual Studio` (I think 2005 is not supported by MS anymore) and then (b) contact Microsoft support, as it seems that the very basics are not working here...